# Dynamic Google Cloud Firestore rules on document ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Thanks for taking the time to read!

What I'm trying to do is dynamically compare the requested document ID against another string saved in the custom claims of a user, using Google Firestore.

I've added the code below (removed the unimportant rules for this question) which from reading the docs *seems* to be correct, but when I try and use these rules it always returns to false. In fact, when I compare `orgId` to a string of the document like `orgId == 'T90101'` that also returns false.

What am I missing?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      // Organization ID saved on the custom claims for this user
      function getMyOrgId() {
        return request.auth.token.organizationId
      }
    
      // BUG: This equates to false but should be true
      function verifyOrganizationClaim(orgId) {
        return getMyOrgId() == orgId;
      }
    
      match /organizations/{orgId} {
        allow create: if false;
        allow delete: if false;
        allow update: if verifyOrganizationClaim(orgId);
        allow read: if verifyOrganizationClaim(orgId);
      } 
   }
}
```

In summary - how do I compare a document ID against a saved custom claim ID, to restrict access to documents?

Any help would be appreciated!

---

Here's the code I'm using to access this data on the client side using React + TypeScript. The error I get is `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

```js
import React from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";
import { useDocumentDataOnce } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";

export const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const MY_ORG_ID = "T01JLKU9W7L"; // This is the same value saved in the custom claims for this user
const EXTERNAL_ORG_ID = "T01JLKU9W7L";

interface Organization {
  id: string;
  displayName: string;
}

const Example: React.FC = () => {
  const [myOrg] = useDocumentDataOnce<Organization>(
    firestore.doc(`organizations/${MY_ORG_ID}`)
  );

  const [externalOrg] = useDocumentDataOnce<Organization>(
    firestore.doc(`organizations/${EXTERNAL_ORG_ID}`)
  );

  return (
    <>
      {/** Should succeed */}
      <div>
        <h1>My Organization</h1>
        <p>Organization Name: {myOrg?.displayName}</p>
        <p>Organization Id: {myOrg?.id}</p>
      </div>
      {/** Should fail */}
      <div>
        <h1>Other Organization</h1>
        <p>Organization Name: {externalOrg?.displayName}</p>
        <p>Organization Id: {externalOrg?.id}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Comment: Can you share the code used to read or write to the database. Security rules without corresponding codes are hard (if not impossible) to debug.

Comment: Thanks for responding @RenaudTarnec I've added a code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your Security Rules in one of my test environment and I can confirm that the `if verifyOrganizationClaim(orgId);` statement does work (together with the two functions).

So I can see three possible reasons why it does not work on your side:

1. Your user is not authenticated
2. You incorrectly assigned the Custom Claim to the user. You can check the custom claims with the following [CLI command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-export): `$ firebase auth:export users.csv`
3. You try to **create** a document, instead of updating or reading it. As a matter of fact your rules only set access rights for updating or reading. (I'm not verse in React and I cannot deduce from the code in your question which operation you execute...)

Comment: I've realised the issue was to do with other fetches causing the app to break at a higher level than this component, which was causing me to falsely identify where the issue was being caused - appreciate your help!